# What is the algorithm to determine a where a card is in a deck using "Low-Down Triple Dealing" magic trick

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, card

Assume you have a deck of cards that's in an JavaScript array `A[1,2,3,4,, n ]` where `A[1] = 1`, `A[2] = 2`, and `A[n] = n`.   The dealer asks the player for a number, say, m, then takes `A[1:m]` off the deck, face down, one-by-one. and places the rest of the deck on top.

What is the position of card A[n] after the cut?

Comment: I think that would work if the card position was greater than m.  But I don't think it would work if it was, for example on the first card A[1] on the deck.  Right?

Comment: If there were 10 cards in the deck, the cut was at 5, and the card in question started at position 1, then after the first 5 cards were placed down, the A[10] would be the value of what used to be A[1].

The new array would be A[6], A[7], A[8], A[9], A[10], A[5], A[4], A[3], A[2], A[1]

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `m=1` and (m<n) then the card will move one position to `A[n-1]` and so if m<=n `A[n]`is at `A[n-m]`.  The new array starting 1 JavaScript array would be `A.slice(m).concat(A.slice(1,m-1).reverse()`.

Using a JavaScript:

```
function cut(A, n, m) {
   //Given array starting at 1, taking m off the top putting in reverse order
   // return the position where the A[n] now is
   if (m <= A.length) {
      alert('Cut point is too large for this deck size.');
   }
   if (m<n) {
      return n-m-1;
   }
   return A.length - n+ 1;
}
```